# How to create a dynamic link with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

so I've been making a "website" hosted on my computer with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot, and I have a basic, insecure login that I made for fun. What I'm currently trying to do is to make a link that brings you back to a previous page based, which is sent in as a String through the model.

Here are a few snippets:
In the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    return ifLoggedIn(model, "home", "");
}

private String ifLoggedIn (Model model, String location, String returnTo) {
    if (Login.loggedIn.getOrDefault(Login.IP(), Boolean.FALSE)) {
        return location;
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
        model.addAttribute("return_page", returnTo);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

In the loggedin.html file (After you log in successfully):

```
<body>
    <a th:href="'/' + ${return_page}">Return to previous location</a>
</body>
```

EDIT:

I first change the line in the loggedin.html file to follow what Pau recommended:

```
<a th:href="@{'/' + ${return}}">Return to previous location</a>
```

But I kept getting redirected to server.local/null, so I tried removing the `'/' +` and having the / inside the ifLoggedIn parameters, so it would be `return ifLoggedIn(model, "home", "/"`, but that also kept sending me to server.local/null. Now, I just changed the line in the loggedin.html file to the following:

```
<a th:if="(${return_page} != null)" th:with="return=(${return_page})" th:href="@{${return}}">Return to previous location</a>
```

Now it just disappears, meaning that ${return_page} is equal to null. Looking back at the controller I don't understand why it returns null. Another thing, I am redirecting back to other pages as well, with one line saying `return ifLoggedIn(model, "messages", "/messages"`, but even with those I still get sent to server.local/null.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use link expressions using `@{...}` which is a type of `Thymeleaf Standard Epression`. In the official doc you can see a lot of examples using expressions inside your link expressions in section `9. Using expressions in URLs`:

- http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

> No problem! Every URL parameter value is in fact an expression, so you can easily substitute your literals with any other expressions, including i18n, conditionals…:
>
> ....
>
> the URL base itself can be specified as an expression, for example a variable expression:
>
> `<a th:href="@{${detailsURL}(id=${order.id})}">`

Furthermore, in the tutorial there is a expressions which is similar as yours, in the section [4.4 Link URLs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls):

> URL bases can also be the result of evaluating another expression:
>
> ...
>
> `<a th:href="@{'/details/'+${user.login}(orderId=${o.id})}">view</a>`

---

So in your case, it would be like next:

```
<body>
    <a th:href="@{'/' + ${return_page}}">Return to previous location</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but that piece of code isn't working for me. Rather than sending me to the previous link (server.local/messages), it sends me to server.local/null. Is it possible that this is caused because I am setting a string to that value?

Comment: `th:href="@{${detailsURL}(id=${order.id})}" `  Doing things like this caused a url like `/user/?id=x` . Managed to make it into expected url using something like this `<a th:href = "${path+'/edit/'+user.id}" `

Answer (score 7):

You can Use This:

### Controller

```
@GetMapping("/userLogin/{userId}")
public String getUserDetailsById(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, Model model){
    return "user/userDetails";
 }
```

### HTML

```
<body>
   <a th:href="@{/userLogin/{userId}(userId=${user.userId})}"></a> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For e.g. here you want to pass the dynamic value of port from your controller then do like this:-

```
<a th:href="@{http://localhost:{port}/index.html(post=${serverPort})}">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
    <a th:href="@{'/' + return_page}">Return to previous location</a>
</body>
```

This works for me