# how to pass pathvariable values during dynamic url in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Actually I am adding Pagination in required page and when I am selecting one value from dropdown then it is not hitting controller(what path given in URL in Request mapping).

This is Thymeleaf code

```
<a id="langEng" class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/custom_report_two/{page}}" target="_blank">All Complainant Representative</a>
```

This is Controller Code

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/custom_report_two/{page}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String customReport_two(@PathVariable(value="page") Integer page, Authentication authentication,
        Model mv, User user) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 3);
    Page<User> userlist = this.userRepository.findAllComplainantReprentativeUser(user.getComplainantType(),
            pageable);
    mv.addAttribute("user", userlist);
    mv.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    mv.addAttribute("totalPages", userlist.getTotalPages());
    return "custom_report_two";
}
```

Comment: You can find some helpful examples in the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls). There are also various answers here on SO - for example: [How to create a dynamic link with Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743317/how-to-create-a-dynamic-link-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot). Various other examples are in [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=thymeleaf+url+links+how+to+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: yes I tried to so many times and read this documentation but still my problem is not solved. I am not able to find error where I am committing mistakes .please can you help it's urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in code. First in SecurityConfiguration Class.

```
.antMatchers("/custom_report_two/{page}").permitAll()
```

and after that I made changes in Thymleaf Page:

```
<a id="langEng" class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/custom_report_two/{page}(page=0)}" target="_blank">All Complainant Representative</a>
```

and in Controller Code nothing changed:

```
@RequestMapping(path ="/custom_report_two/{page}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String customReport_two(@PathVariable(value="page") Integer page, Authentication authentication,
        Model mv, User user) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 1);
    Page<User> userlist = this.userRepository.findAllComplainantReprentativeUser(user.getComplainantType(),
            pageable);
    mv.addAttribute("user", userlist);
    mv.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    mv.addAttribute("totalPages", userlist.getTotalPages());
    return "custom_report_two";
}
```

now it is working fine and this is going in Controller and Displaying values in DataTables.

Comment: @{/custom_report_two/{page} here i dont think it will replace page value..

Answer (score 0):

The another way of passing path variable is as below

```
<a id="langEng" class="dropdown-item"
 th:href="@{/custom_report_two/}+${page}" target="_blank">
 All Complainant Representative</a>
```